# vm-tools: copy/paste not working or incorrect scaling

Tags: linux-mint, vmware

I newbie with Linux. Just installed Mint in a virtual machine (VMware) and get a problem with vm-tools:

When switching between fullscreen and windowed, the screen scale resets to 200% (I need 150% for my monitor). Also, if I change screen scale manually the mouse gets locked in the virtual machine window and I have to press CTRL+ALT to release the cursor. Other features work.

By default, `open-vm-tools` is installed on the system.
I tried removing `open-vm-tools` (and `open-vm-tools-desktop`) with the command:
`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove open-vm-tools-desktop`
then installed "VMware Tools":

> Player > Manage > Install VMware Tools ...
> extract archive
> run `sudo ./vmware-install.pl`

After reboot, no scaling issues when switching window modes - this works great. The mouse moves freely in the VM and back. But copy/paste stops working!
Google says that in this case you need to install `open-vm-tools-desktop`. It helps, but the scaling problem comes back.
Both functions are important for me))

Host OS: Windows 10 Pro
VMware® Workstation 17 Player (17.0.1)
Guest OS: Mint 21.1 (Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-56-generic)

Answer (score 0):

I found an unexpected workaround:
you can install KDE Plasma to Mint and it works fine with `open-vm-tools`! scaling doesn't reset, copy/paste works.

I used `tasksel` to install.